# Doesn't find sqlite .db file on PC

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I took backup of sqlite database to external storage. It's available when i open file explorer in android.But i can't see the same file in my personal computer. I have connected device with my personal computer through USB. What was problem in device or computer?

Comment: try listing in adb shell.

Comment: are you save DB file in your sd card ?

Comment: If your database file is not in sdcard, you must move it by adb shell (cat database.db >> /sdcard/...) and then you can find it with the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside Windows -> showView -> others -> Android -> FileExplorer -> data -> data-> yourApplication ->DB file :
```

how to export.

[image: how to export database]